# Prove that operator is linear. Find its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Reflection with respect to the plane $X+Y=0$

---

Wiki says, that An important special case is when $V = W$, in which case the map is called a linear operator.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map How to show that in my case the operator is also linear. And what is its matrix?

Comment: What are $V$ and $W$? What have you tried? Please add more context.

Comment: @JohnDoe given that he characterizes $X + Y = 0$ as a plane and given the article he's linked, it seems that $V = W = \Bbb R^3$.  What he's trying to prove, then, is that reflection through a plane is a linear operator.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes of course, and I too was able to deduce this. I feel it is good practice for it to be made clear in the question, along with some thoughts on the problem. This was the reason for my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to determine the operator as $T(x,y,z) = (-y,-x,z)$. (Hint: Break the vector into vectors along the normal of the plane (say v) and a vector lying in the plane (say w). I.e, our given vector (x,y,z) = v+w. Now, our reflected vector is r = -v+w ). Now, it is easy to check that our operator is linear, as we have to verify that the equality $T((x_1,y_1,z_1)+c*(x_2,y_2,z_2)) = T(x_1,y_1,z_1)+c*T(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, holds true.
For finding out the matrix of the transformation, it is enough to find the result of the transformation on basis vectors. As it is not specified in the question, we assume $V = W = \mathbb R^3$. Then, T(1,0,0) = (0,-1,0), T(0,1,0) = (-1,0,0) and T(0,0,1) = (0,0,1).
More generally it is possible to prove that reflection about any plane, rotation about any axis constitute orthogonal linear operators.

Comment: So, matrix is (0,-1,0)|(-1,0,0)|(0,0,1)?

Comment: First row (0,-1,0), not (0,0,0). Right?

Comment: yeap, I got it. But T(0,1,0)=(-1,0,0), so the second column is (-1,0,0) => first row is (0,-1,0)

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see carefully. You are right. The transformation is obviously invertible too, so the first comment doesn't make any sense.